# Issue with Regular Expression Validation

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have an Asp.Net script which includes a validator like this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="AdvNeedIdValidator" runat="server"
  ControlToValidate="NEEDS" ErrorMessage="Need ID is numeric."
  ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^\d*\.?\d*$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The validator is supposed to reject non-numeric inputs (`NEEDS` is a numeric value) but I think there is problem with the regular expression `"^\d*\.?\d*$"` because when I want to clear the Input text the when  the user enter the text the `ErrorMessage` pops up. I have a NeedID field with 4 number numeric value,so can you please let me know how I can upgrade the  `"^\d*\.?\d*$"` to get rid of that Issue?

Thanks

Comment: To be honest no I am not , but when I remove the validator from code the application works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to validate a 4 digit whole number, try using the following:

```
^\d{4}$
```

---

`^\d` means start with any digit

`{4}` means there must be exactly 4.

`$` means that is the end of the pattern.

So in other words, the regex validates and expression of exactly 4 digits.

Comment: thanks but how about getting rid of space? I mean how to prevent user to insert a nbumber like this 4444 2222?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to validate numbers such as:

500.40
30
0.02
.02

this should meet what you're looking for:

"\d*\.?\d+"

Comment: Hi user3320441, thanks for reply what I have is a whole number with 4 digits. so I do not want to have something like 500.40 or .02 or even 30! what I need is having something like 5555 or 3333. a four digits whole number(xxxx). Can you please let me know how I can update you expression to only accept that?

Comment: @Behseini if you don't want any decimal points in your number, your regex should simply be `"\d+"` or `"[0-9]+"`

Comment: @adback03 thanks but how about limiting the character size to 4?

Comment: @Behseini See my answer above.